# ContextMenu text overflowing

Tags: android, contextmenu, word-wrap

I am trying to place a ContextMenu on my ListActivity when the user clicks on any list item, which displays several sub-categories. Don't bother telling me other alternatives (ExpandableList, RadioButton, etc).

How can I get the FULL text to show up, instead of it being truncated? Here is how I am populating the ContextMenu:

```
    @Override  
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  

        //Fill context menu with appropriate subcategory
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Categories");
        for(String item : menuItem)
        {
            menu.add(0, v.getId(), menu.size()+1, item);
        }
    }
```

*Note that menuItem is simply a String[ ] array*

Here is my ContextMenu. [ContextMenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8wrQ.png)
I feel like a moron having not enough reputation to post pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know of would be to create your menu from XML rather than just in code and change the text size so all your text will fit.  I looked around for a bit and could find no information on any way to change the text size of the program generated menu.

Docs regarding creating a context menu from XML are [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#FloatingContextMenu).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue; however, I am using a menu resource xml instead of setting the titles via code.

A menu item can contain both a title and a "android:titleCondensed" for scenarios where the title would be truncated.

From what I can tell, if you need more custom behavior you will need to specify your own layout resources to describe the more complex behavior compared with what a standard Android menu resource provides.  Essentially you can override the default layout with your own.

If you are setting strings programmatically to achieve a context menu with different items at different time, you could consider specifying the titles and condensed titles in the xml menu resource, then in onCreateContextMenu, you can add logic to call "setMenuItemVisibility" for each item to filter out the items you do not want displayed at any given time.

Comment: I neglected to leave a reference to the Android Menu resource: [Android Menu Resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html)